# Filter by date in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am having trouble filtering data by dates which will filter only active permits.
I have a set of data coming in through an importrange.(A1)

```
=ImportRange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aA_yAOnGa_yJOguCd9f24qWohFj3ciBCwqZiBfIf2Z4/edit?usp=sharing","Formula1!M1:Q10")
```

Today's date is set (G2)

```
=TODAY()
```

I showed the wished result under active permits

Under test formula you can see the formula I put, but only one line comes up.

```
=query({A1:E},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 where Col1 is not null "&if(len(G2)," and Col3 <= date '"&text(G2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ",)&if(len(G2)," and Col4 >= date '"&text(G2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ",)&" ",1)
```

I tested when instead of getting data from an importrange I get them by copy and paste and the formula works. See `Copy of Sheet1` tab

The wished result is to get the query to only import the permits which are active (Today is between start and end date)

Please help

Link to test sheet  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JYedYUt15SFJ50P-8Wxv4akYLmZKTkdss9vvvMQ4hUw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **01** - Format date and time correctly, these cells have 15, 20 months `X_X`

[image]

> **02** - **Use this formula** with i adjusted the col selection,

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("1R13d4k1q3P7KbSGCYHP7a5oWLl4BjWGwjNL8-40AVIM","Sheet1!A1:E"),"
       select * where Col1 is not null "&if(len(K2)," 
       and Col3 <= date '"&text(K2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ",)&if(len(K2)," 
       and Col4 >= date '"&text(K2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ",)&" ",1)
```

[image]
**Note**: the yellow table to check the logic you want, return the rows when start is <= `TODAY()` And End is >= `TODAY()`, and the returned result is correct, your desierd output end date is proir to `TODAY()` see the red cells, and its correct in the source data

[image]

Comment: It still gives one line of answer :(

Comment: Make the source sheet accessible by everyone so i can get to it and test it im talking about this `"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aA_yAOnGa_yJOguCd9f24qWohFj3ciBCwqZiBfIf2Z4/edit?usp=sharing"` if you can

Comment: I made the source file available now here {https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16MYz8RpoKovDSOJX9suBDN9pus_Jzwd3K_1qxZlh8B8/edit?usp=sharing}

Comment: Clarify this please!.. "The wished result is to get the query to only import the permits which are active (Today is between start and end date)"

Comment: I mean the permits showing are not expired. Today is between start and end dates of permits

Comment: Hi @player0 Please can you check this answer, here is [my answer sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tTsJ2PQ8V1Dd6jsQNZFQzZDaAWr_0lpUh3UrE1gASh8/edit?usp=sharing) and this is a copy of the [OP source sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R13d4k1q3P7KbSGCYHP7a5oWLl4BjWGwjNL8-40AVIM/edit?usp=sharing) "it's a copy because he stoped sharing his", Im not 100% sure of my answer, any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your column C and D are [formatted](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?hl=en) as dates, the following works.

```
 =filter(A2:E,not(isblank(A2:A),C2:C<=today(),D2:D>=today())
```

Otherwise, you may need to add `to_date()` by replacing with `D2:D` with `arrayformula(to_date(D2:D))` (and same with `C2:C`). Or you may need to parse the dates data with something else. Just be careful of what actually constitutes the dates data in your database. (Date serials? Strings with a format that Google Sheet accepts by default? Or not? etc. In any case, converting particular strings to be compatible for datatime arithmetic in Google Sheet can be its own question.)

Consult official documentation on [filter](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) for more info.